# NullPointerException when running Spring Rest app

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I get this while accessing a Spring Resource from the browser `127.0.0.1:8080/` I wonder why its throwing this error:

```
[INFO] java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]  at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:2842)
[INFO]  at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:2828)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.hateoas.config.HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:96)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:340)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:233)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:154)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:131)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:254)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:305)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:97)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
[INFO]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is similar issue, I think upgrading Spring to never patch level version should help: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-210